# Export-Csv - Added new properties doesn't export

Tags: powershell, csv, export, pst

This is my very first StackOverflow post so I will try to be undestandable as much as possible :D

I'm parsing some **.pst** files to get all the mails and their properties and then export them as **.csv** files.
The thing is I don't want the attachments as a list or string. **I want to create a new column in the CSV for each of them.**

Let's say this are my datas :

```
Sender       : bla@bla.com
Receiver     : blu@blu.com
Subject      : How not to die
Attachments  : BestCatPic.jpg BestDogPic.jpg
```

Then I add each attachments as new properties (`$piece` is a number):
`$email | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attachment-$piece" -NotePropertyValue "$e"`

And this is working because then my datas looks like this :

```
Sender       : bla@bla.com
Receiver     : blu@blu.com
Subject      : How not to die
Attachments  : BestCatPic.jpg BestDogPic.jpg
Attachment-1 : BestCatPic.jpg 
Attachment-2 : BestDogPic.jpg
```

My problem is that when I use `Export-Csv`, the datas are the same as if I didn't used `add-member` and the new properties like `Attachment-1` does not appears in my CSV file.

Here is my Export-Csv line (`$email_out` is my list of all mails):
`$email_out | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 $pstName -NoTypeInformation`

Do you guys have any idea why or what could help ?

Comment: When you export to csv the columns are created from the first item. You cannot add columns after this. Either create ALL the fields you need to start with using a "dummy" entry or compile a PSobject holding all the data and then send to csv when complete.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed)

Comment: Or use the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58915598/9898643)

Comment: I already added them manually but this looks like a good way too ! Thanks